# HTML5 paint brush tip

Tags: html, brush

I'm trying to get a round brush tip, but the code below creates a brush tip with the shape of a line.

```
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.lineCap = "round";
```

How to get a round brush tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to draw a path to your canvas and set `lineCap` to `round`.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(10, 10);
context.lineTo(canvas.width/2, canvas.height / 2);
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = "red";
context.lineCap = "round";
context.stroke();
```

See also this [example in the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/4_6_canvas_linecap.html).